# SciPy: leastsq vs least_squares

Tags: scipy, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

SciPy provides two functions for nonlinear least squares problems:

`optimize.leastsq()` uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm only.

`optimize.least_squares()` allows us to choose the Levenberg-Marquardt, Trust Region Reflective, or Trust Region Dogleg algorithm.

Should we always use `least_squares()` instead of `leastsq()`?

If so, what purpose does the latter serve?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Short answer

> Should we always use least_squares() instead of leastsq()?

Yes.

> If so, what purpose does the latter serve?

Backward compatibility.

#### Explanation

The `least_squares` function is new in 0.17.1. Its [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) refers to `leastsq` as

> A legacy wrapper for the MINPACK implementation of the Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm.

The [original commit](https://github.com/nmayorov/scipy/blob/7ef2cd0d6a68592ddb4ca89cc7bc15c220dca329/scipy/optimize/least_squares.py#L351) introducing `least_squares` actually called `leastsq` when the method was chosen to be 'lm'. But the contributor (Nikolay Mayorov) then [decided that](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5019)

> least_squares might feel more solid and homogeneous if I write a new wrapper to MINPACK functions, instead of calling leastsq.

and so he did. So, `leastsq` is no longer required by `least_squares`, but I'd expect it to be kept at least for a while, to avoid breaking old code.

Comment: In my experiments it turned out that `leastsq` is some 10-15% faster than `least_squares`. Can you comment on this?